# Time obtained from SQLite DB always 00:00

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I have developed a messaging app and I write the sent message to the SQLITE DB with message body and time. Here is the method -

```
@Override
    public void onMessageSendClick(TextMessage textMessage) {
        sendTextMessage(textMessage.getBody());
        Log.d("hi","Send = " + textMessage.getSendDate());
        storeSentMessagesInDB(new MessagesHistoryItem(textMessage.getBody(), textMessage.isFromDevice(), textMessage.getSendDate()));
    }

    private void storeSentMessagesInDB(MessagesHistoryItem textMessage){
        sqlitehandler.insert(driver, server, textMessage);
    }
```

The log `Send = Thu Sep 08 19:04:10 GMT+04:00 2016`

The problem is when I read from DB, I get time as always `00:00`. Here is the code -

```
Date date;
private final SimpleDateFormat formatDateDB = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                try {
                    date = formatDateDB.parse(dbCursor.getString(4));
                    Log.d("hi","Retrieve =" + date);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    date = new Date();
                }
```

The log `Retrieve = Thu Sep 08 00:00:00 GMT+04:00 2016` and my messaging chat appears with time `00:00`. Why is this problem?

Comment: First thing is to check what's actually in the database -- if it's not stored a time, you can't get one back! Assuming it has, a first guess would be because your `SimpleDateFormat()` specification doesn't include any time components... `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` perhaps?

Comment: show property declaration for MessagesHistoryItem

Comment: @TripeHound I tried with dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss but still the same problem